# swing textField orientation

Tags: java, swing

Hi i want to display text from right to left, im using setComponentOrientation but in my case, the text i want to display is a decimal number, and the dot first appears at the left side of the text and when i add another number than the dot moves to the right as it should have been in the first place.. check the photos for a better understanding of my issue. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9yhU.jpg)

```
This is just the textfield part.
textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(55, 42, 158, 29);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    textField.setBorder(null);
    textField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be using `setHorizontalAlignment()` instead of `setComponentOrientation()`.